# Synchronisation issue with Mongo request

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to perform a mongodb request, wait until it end and return a result.

The issue is the instruction after the mongo request looks like to be executed before the request end or even start.

```
users_opposite = collection.find( {"mode" : opposite} ).forEach(function (usersOpposite) {

    users_closed.push(usersOpposite);
    console.log(users_closed.length);
});
console.log(users_closed.length);
console.log("test");
```

As a result I'm getting this

> > 0
> >     test
> >     1
> >     2
> >     3
> >     4

How can I say to the following instruction to wait until the foreach is complete ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait the execution of collection.find()

```
// giving a context for the code
async function foo() {

    // something before

    users_opposite = await collection.find( {"mode" : opposite} )
        .forEach(function (usersOpposite) {
            users_closed.push(usersOpposite);
            console.log(users_closed.length);
        });

    console.log(users_closed.length);
    console.log("test");
}
```

As already suggested by Grégory in the comment, more info here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `forEach` but `collection.find` needs to complete, then you can get the results in a callback, like:

```
collection.find({ mode: opposite }, function(err, usersOpposite) {
    console.log(usersOpposite);
});
```

Comment: Can't make this work. I know I make things bad...I'm getting an error with the following  `collection.find({ mode: opposite }, function(err, usersOpposite) {
                console.log(usersOpposite);
            }).forEach(function (usersOpposite) {
                users_closed.push(usersOpposite);
                console.log(users_closed.length);
            });`